# Genymotion with Cocos2d-x v3.11

Tags: android, c++, genymotion, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-x-3.x

I am using cocos2d-x v3.11 on mac and using Genymotion virtual devices.

In my `/jni/Application.mk`, I've put,

```
APP_ABI :=armeabi armeabi-v7a
APP_ABI :=x86
```

But always same error comes `NO_MATCHING_ABIS` and the app doesn't launch on the genymotion.

Though error log may not be needed but here it is:

`D/dalvikvm( 1893): Late-enabling CheckJNI
I/ActivityManager(  587): Start proc org.company.numbergame for activity org.company.numbergame/org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity: pid=1893 uid=10060 gids={50060, 3003}
D/dalvikvm( 1893): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/org.company.numbergame-1/libMyGame.so 0xa4fe4688
E/dalvikvm( 1893): dlopen("/data/app-lib/org.company.numbergame-1/libMyGame.so") failed: dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/libhoudini.so" not found
D/AndroidRuntime( 1893): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 1893): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d17b20)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1893): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 1893): Process: org.company.numbergame, PID: 1893
E/AndroidRuntime( 1893): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/libhoudini.so" not found
E/AndroidRuntime( 1893):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:364)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1893):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1893):    at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onLoadNativeLibraries(Cocos2dxActivity.java:246)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1893):    at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onCreate(Cocos2dxActivity.java:260)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1893):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1893):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1893):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1893):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1893):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1893):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1893):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1893):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1893):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1893):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1893):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1893):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1893):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1893):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  587):   Force finishing activity org.company.numbergame/org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity
D/dalvikvm(  587): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 856K, 19% free 8972K/10964K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
D/MobileDataStateTracker(  587): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=true)
W/ActivityManager(  587): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{529f9534 u0 org.company.numbergame/org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity t8 f}
W/EGL_genymotion(  763): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
D/MobileDataStateTracker(  587): default: setPolicyDataEnable(enabled=t`

The eclipse emulators are really slow and I need to use Genymotion also for multi-device resolution testing.

**EDIT:**
A strange issue, I noticed after restarting eclipse. (I din't change my Application.mk). When I built project using `cocos compile -p android`
then it started building for x86 and worked when installed on genymotion device but didn't work for my actual devices. And when I removed x86 then it built for armeabi . But it doesn't work simultaneously on both kind of devices(armeabi and x86).

Does anyone know, how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Genymotion works on x86 architecture. If you want to run an ARM build on genymotion then [download the ARM translation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mslymgc4fmhhig0/Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip?dl=1) and drop it on your genymotion emulator, then it will start accepting ARM build.